# How do I add an alias in a SQL inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like so:

```
Table Name: Foo
Foo Columns: (ID, UNIQUE_ID, NAME)

Table Name: Bar
Bar Columns (FOO_ID, UNIQUE_ID, NAME)
```

I basically want all `bars` that belong to a particular `foo`, and the result should be two columns `UNIQUE_ID` and `NAME` of each `bar`.

My SQL looks like so:

```
SELECT UNIQUE_ID, NAME FROM BAR B INNER JOIN FOO F ON F.ID = B.FOO_ID WHERE F.UNIQUE_ID = 123
```

I provide the `UNIQUE_ID`. The problem is that both tables have a `UNIQUE_ID` column, so I receive the following error: `SQL Error: ambiguous column name: UNIQUE_ID`. How do I add in alias for the column in `Foo` so that my result of `UNIQUE_ID` and `NAME` contains the unique ID of `Bar`? I don't want an alias for the `UNIQUE_ID` column in `Bar`.. the result should have the actual column name.

Comment: Have you tried  `F.UNIQUE_ID, B.NAME`? In addition, the last to avoid an ambiguous column for your col name.

Comment: @forpas without the inner join it's not tied to a particular `Foo`. The `FOO_ID` is a foreign key referencing to the `Foo` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT B.UNIQUE_ID, B.NAME
FROM BAR B INNER JOIN
     FOO F
     ON F.ID = B.FOO_ID
WHERE F.UNIQUE_ID = 123
```

You should qualify all column references in the query.

Comment: oh man.. I don't know how I missed that haha. Brain fart.. actually you were very close. But instead of `SELECT F.UNIQUE_ID` I was looking for `SELECT B.UNIQUE_ID`. And since both tables have `NAME` it would have to also be `B.NAME`. It works perfectly